# open id created a new account for me (request to re-open close post)

Tags: bug, login, user-accounts, openid, linked-accounts

I'm on a different computer and the Open ID login created on new account on the SO site.

Using the Open ID login on the SO site created a new account for me.  It appears to be new.  But it also showed my previously entered personal details.  Very confusing.  **I think someone took pity and may have reset my account.**  If not, I could be in trouble.

The only difference is that I am using a different computer today.  I am not the least bit concerned really except...

**See:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/logging-into-stackoverflow-created-a-new-user-account**

**Could someone re-open that post?**  I can't request that.

Please note that it was **closed as too localized.**  I assume it will **disappear from the site very soon**.  Dunno, but it is not too localized:

1. It is an ongoing problem.
2. Only users having the problem care... but may be quite a bit.
3. Is has a answer.
4. It creates confusion among new users.
5. It probably junks up the SO system.
6. It gives the appearance of creating duplicate accounts.

**The advice was I can email: team@stackoverflow.com** but I won't bother them.  I was going to ask: Can someone have a look at my accounts or comment on this? and **would have if I had not seen that post**.

Now this specific post really is too localized and should be deleted once it gets a Yea or Nay.

Best Regards, info for support:

> SO Site Ids:
>   meta-SO: DHorse, [user228676](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/228676/)
>   SO: [DHorse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420629/)

Note:
Considering my recent comments on new users creating duplicate accounts...  (I know duplicate account are for development project security reasons only.) This makes me look REALLY suspicious.  Kind of funny really.  I'm innocent, I was not planning to test that until later this year.

**25 Jul 13 8:00AM Update and answer to this case:**
The next morning I had this message:

> Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is
>   already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our
>   account recovery page to get access to this account.

This occurred when I tried to update the profile.

In addition:
I very **strongly suspect** (while not wearing glasses) **that I clicked "sign up" at the top thinking it was "sign in"**.  This would explain it.  At that top the **sign up page it said "Log In"** where the list of Open ID images is displayed.  What shows varies a lot, so it is only under certain circumstances.  In other cases I got AddLogin.

I'm betting this was a case of operator error. I.E. my first click to "sign in(UP)" rather than "log in", compounded by minor issues that followed. (Note to self: wear glasses.)

There may be an additional factor that my Open ID email (Google) is different from the email on my account (Hotmail.)  I don't know.

**25 July 13 9:12AM Update**

1. I requested a reset and followed the link in the email.
2. This restored my account on SO including the newbie rep and block.
3. When I attempted to update my profile I again got the above Oops! message.  Oops again. :)

I noticed the multiple accounts were oddly disconnected.  My meta-SO account took me back to the duplicate SO account.  It is interesting that I have also seen accounts for programmer-SO and Web Applications SO appear over time.  I wasn't really active on them, I curious about the how and why of their appearance.

However, it is note worthy that my meta-SO account does not appear on my SO account.  My meta-SO account now lists the correct SO account (minutes later.)  It would appear that there are some transaction processing as well as bulk (scheduled) updating taking place.

BTW Logging everything off (including Google) does not appear related to any of the issues.  Similarly, leaving other accounts logged on.  I also do not think cookies or sessions are an influence, as said, I suspect minor UI issues and transaction processing are involved.

**Immediate Update**
And now I can update my SO profile.  There you go.  I'm going to use this as a case study the next time I get into a debate about TP vs dynamically updated (lock based) customer service applications.  I.E. Costs vs spurious trouble reports.

Comment: I do not see the user you're mentioning.

Comment: @hjpotter92  Hmmmm.  I can't explain that.  The user seems to be DHorse on both sites.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I was able to do a needed update to: [IE8 and IE9 - Expected ';' error on comment lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185170/ie8-and-ie9-expected-error-on-comment-lines)  It is willing to let me start a question but I don't want to try a test question.  The above question should point to the account though.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I don't want to waste you time though...  Should the other post be reopened?

Comment: Wait until someone from SO staff takes a look at the problem.

Comment: The post to be re-opened is: [Logging into stackoverflow created a new user account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64202/logging-into-stackoverflow-created-a-new-user-account*)

Comment: No need to reopen  that old post. Asking again is fine in my opinion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think you put in a good edit and it got hammered by my own.  If so, my apologies.  Can that happen?  I will of course look again for the edit and check the answers. I think there was a change to this text: "Update and answer to this case:"

Comment: I just made the list be formatted as list and put your contact details as a quote block, both are fine now. :)